# how to loop through an object with an interval time to change a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, javascript-objects

i am trying to loop through a javascript object to change background-image to other images every 3 seconds.

i know i will be using setInterval, a for-loop to go through the object and jQuery to access the css and change the background. but i am not sure about how to use all that together

HTML

```
<div class="example"></div>
```

CSS

```
    .example {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(path/pic01.jpeg); }
```

JS

```
  var header = {
pic01 : 'url(path/pic02.jpeg)',
pic02 : 'url(path/pic03.jpeg)',
pic03 : 'url(path/pic04.jpeg)',
pic04 : 'url(path/pic05.jpeg)'}
```

i tried:

```
   var counter = 0;
   var i = setInterval(function(){


    counter++;
    if(counter === 5) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 3000);
```

and something like this. but i can't seem to get it done

```
for (var key in header) {
if (header.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
console.log(header[key]);

})

}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Look into JavaScript `setTimout`

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) tells it all, with examples ...

Comment: i tried a lot of things. i know the logic behind it and i understand it. but i can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: i know i will be using setInterval, a for-loop to go through the object and  jQuery  to access the css and change the background. but i am not sure about how to use all that together

Answer (score 2):

Why not use CSS?

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body, .example {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.example {
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-name: gallery;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1, start);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes gallery {
  0%, 100% {
    background-image: url(https://placebear.com/145/201)
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url(https://placebear.com/395/205)
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url(https://placebear.com/150/200)
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url(https://placebear.com/145/300)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

Comment: This is better than the javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, use an array for the header images, that makes it a little easier. Below are two functions that will either loop infinite, starting from 0 index once the array's length is reached, the other one will loop the array once until all elements have been shown once. (You'll need to adjust it to your needs instead of writing the text to the div...)

```js
var header = [
  'url(path/pic02.jpeg)',
  'url(path/pic03.jpeg)',
  'url(path/pic04.jpeg)',
  'url(path/pic05.jpeg)'
];
var i = 0;

function loopInfinite(arr) {
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = arr[i];
  i++;
  if (i === arr.length) i = 0;
  setTimeout(() => {
    loopInfinite(arr);
  }, 500);
}

function loopOnce(arr) {
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = arr[i];
  i++;
  if (i < arr.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      loopOnce(arr);
    }, 500);
  }
}


loopInfinite(header);
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this codeblock:

```
var counter = 0;
   var i = setInterval(function(){


    counter++;
    if(counter === 5) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 3000);
```

You have not included your background-updating code.  Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
var imageNumber = 0;
var counter = 0;
   var i = setInterval(function(){

    counter++;
    if(counter === 5) {

        // your background-updating code
        $('.example').css('background-image',headers['pic0' + imageNumber]);
        imageNumber++;
        if (imageNumber > headers.length) {
          imageNumber = 0;
        }


        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 3000);
```